# How to get data types of columns when a CREATE TABLE FROM SELECT is forbidden?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've finished a big query in SSMS with a lot of columns. The result will be inserted in another server.

Usually, I create a temporary table to quickly get the data types of each columns (`CREATE TABLE` from a `SELECT`).

But now, I'm working on a server where it is forbidden to create a table (even a temporary one).

How can I get the structure of my query easily, without re-typing each column manually?

EDIT 1 :
I query on an Azure SQL Server Database.
And my result will go to an On Premise SQL Server.

EDIT 2 :
SQL Server 2016

Comment: What product are you using? Only SQL Server data warehouse product supports [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas). Is that what you are using? The equivalent elsewhere in SQL Server is `SELECT ...  INTO`

Comment: You can use "Export data..." function of the SSMS to see the data types

Comment: What version of SQL Server? You shouldn't need to create anything on modern versions in order to determine the shape of a resultset, assuming your query can be dynamic SQL or is in an object. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4868/1186

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Bertrand, it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a query that you can construct as dynamic SQL (or in an object), you can usually inspect the types involved using [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT database_id, name FROM sys.databases;';

SELECT name, 
       system_type_name, 
       is_nullable
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0) AS f
ORDER BY f.column_ordinal;
```

Results ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f09192755b35919f69cb3a8e744ff16d)):

| name | system_type_name | is_nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| database_id | int | False |
| name | nvarchar(128) | True |

So you could use that output to build a `CREATE TABLE` statement, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(max), 
        @create nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.DBs
(--';
 
SET @sql = N'SELECT database_id, name FROM sys.databases;';
 
SELECT @create += ',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '  '
               + name + ' ' 
               + system_type_name 
               + CASE is_nullable WHEN 0 THEN ' NOT' ELSE ' ' END
               + ' NULL'
  FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0) AS f;
 
SELECT @create += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N');';
 
PRINT @create;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @create;
```

Output ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5fad57fa71eb5386b22be01261b91147)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DBs
(--,
  database_id int NOT NULL,
  name nvarchar(128)  NULL
);
```

Some background:

- [SQL Server v.Next (Denali) : Metadata enhancements](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/20/sql-server-v-next-denali-metadata-enhancements)
- [How can I get a list of column names and types from a resultset?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4868/1186)